# Windows Phone 7 ListBox has bad performance with just a few items?

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, listbox

I'm writing a simple dictionary app which gives suggestions for words as you type. The suggestions are displayed in a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and each time the query changes, about 10 suggestions should appear.

Unfortunately, performance is low at the moment. It takes almost a second for the results to appear and I don't understand why. [EQATEC Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/Home.aspx) shows that my methods are running smoothly. I've confirmed this by putting a [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) around my code. I've also experimented with the number of suggestions, and performance does increase with fewer items.

This leads me to conclude that rendering the ListBox (which I presume happens outside of my methods) is to blame for the lack of performance.

- Does rendering 10 items in a ListBox really take more than 250ms?
- How can I quickly put a small number of words on the screen?

Edit:
The way I fill my ListBox is very straightforward. Is it the right way?

```
resultsListBox.Items.Clear();
foreach (string s in suggestions.Words)
{
  resultsListBox.Items.Add(s);
}
resultsListBox.SelectedIndex = suggestions.MatchIndex;
```

What you see here is really it: default ListBox, String items, no templates. Do I violate one of these principals?

- Ensure you have the item data template in a fixed sized container (grid).
- Avoid/remove using complex converters, when the same information can be easily provided by the data object.
- Avoid/remove nested structures, example listbox in a listbox item.
- Strongly recommended to not use user control inside the data template.
- Avoid/remove custom controls from the data template

---

The link below contains a demonstration of the ListBox performance in a simple project.

The project also shows an alternative (faster) way to display a list, using a Grid with Buttons. This list is not scrollable and therefore *not a real solution*.

http://www.mediafire.com/?jypcfm4cs3nvo5c

Remember to run the project on a device, because the emulator has very different performance. I've tested it on the Samsung Omnia 7.

Comment: The link below contains a demonstration of the ListBox performance in a simple project.

The project also shows an alternative (faster) way to display a list, using a Grid with Buttons. This list is not scrollable and therefore <i>not a real solution</i>.

http://www.mediafire.com/?jypcfm4cs3nvo5c

Remember to run the project on a device, because the emulator has very different performance. I've tested it on the Samsung Omnia 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're creating your own AutoCompleteBox. Is there a specific reason for not using the one in the [Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034)?

I would expect the time taken to update the listbox to be dependent upon: how you're updating it; the complexity of the listbox; and whatever-else is on the page.
In that you haven't provided details about any of these it could be possible that it will take this long.

---

**Edit**
As an alternative to the `AutoCompleteBox` (In theory you shouldn't need to scroll the results of this--just enter more characters to filter further.) I've done some experimentation and the following seems to work best. It uses a `StackPanel` inside a `ScrollViewer` and reuses the existing items, rather than creating new ones.

```
<ScrollViewer Height="629" Margin="0,139,0,0" Width="480">
    <StackPanel Name="listBox1" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

cs:

```
    private void InitializeResultsGrid()
    {
        ...

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            ...

            listBox1.Children.Add(new TextBlock());
```

and

```
private void SlowFill(string baseStr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count; i++)
    {
        (listBox1.Children[i] as TextBlock).Text = baseStr + (char)(i + 'a');
    }
```

When I timed it, it was slightly slower than using the Grid but the performace seemed fine to me on an LG-E900

Comment: Thanks for your tip about the AutoCompleteBox. As far as I can see it's not a scrollable list though, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Clearing the ListBox might be the cause of bad performance, but do they really expect programmers to re-use items in a ListBox, instead of removing them and adding a new object?

Comment: @Mathijs If you can provide a complete working example that shows the slow loading I'll investigate further.

Comment: I've provided an example in the 'solution' below. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Thanks. This is probably as close as you'll get to a listbox, without actually using a listbox :)